# SQL aliasing to redirect traffic between databases on the same server

Tags: sql-server-2008

In order to upgrade a database with no client disconnects, I clone an existing database and put it in a readonly mode. Now, I want all user traffic to be redirected from the original database to the cloned one (both are on the same server). I want to do it with SQL aliases. However, I see that aliasing is possible for server instances and protocols. Is there another way to go about database redirects on the same server?

Comment: Yes, rename your databases.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are only for server/instances of SQL Server, not for databases.

In your case I'd create a [database snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx) of the current database (so there's no need for a new read-only copy of your db), redirect all user connections there, do you update, then drop the snapshot. Please take into consideration that a snapshot can take a lot of space if forgotten there, not dropped on time.

Comment: +1 for I think this is the way to go unless you have access to a redundant server and mirroring or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thats something easily achieved in this way. Youll probably want something similar to transactional replication / failover. Not sure how your structure has altered though. If the structure isnt changing, I would run with this solution so that you can take down the original and everything will simply divert.